# How can I add a picture to a Database using DataBindign

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to add a picture to a Database using DataBindign but I don't know how to do it .
this is the code i used to load the image:

byte[] imgData;

```
 private void simpleButton5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                picture.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image.\n You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Database and data binding are different things. What exactly you want to know?

Comment: for example if I want to add a string i use this : 

textbox1.DataBindings.Add("text", sql.ds.Tables["E"], "NUMETU");

how can I add a picture ??

Comment: But your data is not coming from database. Why do you need data bindings? Just add a PictureBox and set its Image: PictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName)

Comment: Yes but this picture is saved in a database and i want my dataGrid to display this image which is in the database because when i run the application, the dataGrid should display all informations which are already in the dataBase also i need to solve this problem because i'm gonna use it to load informations in anothoer form

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code how you can read BLOB (in Oracle) files from database. I hope it will help you a bit:

```
    private void ReadFileFromDatabase()
    {
        byte[] fileData = null;

        string selectSql = "SELECT FILE_DATA FROM BLOBTEST WHERE FILE_ID=1";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(selectSql, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    fileData = (byte[])reader["FILE_DATA"];
                    //do your operations with fileData here
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```